# Visiting a div which is nested inside other div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing PyQt application, and using javascript sctipt I want to get to some div's on website. Unfortunately when viewing page source there is only one top div (a kind of wrapper for the whole content). The div which I am looking for is nested about seven times. I know how it is called, because I inspected the page. I don't know how to get to this div, because it is nested, and viewing html of the page only shows one top div.

Comment: `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector`.

Comment: But I am using QWebEngineWiew.page() which return content for current html document  and there is only this on top div. And script can't find div which is nested, because in main html document there is only one top div.

Comment: You can use jquery. $('div').each(some function);

Comment: But i want to execute script only for one div which is significant for me. Not for all divs.

Comment: You can use `QWebEngineWiew.page().children`